# issue in loading user after Authenticated

Tags: reactjs

i am facing issue in loading authenticated(login) user , i used jwt for authentication (used localStorage to store token) ... once user successfully logedIn,he is redirected to homepage thats working fine but when i reload the page is redirected to login page... but desired functionality is that , if he reloads ones authenticate he should not redirected login ,it should reload home page till user click to logout ... this is my code ...i don't know where i went wrong...

this is login in function

```
 const loginUser = async (userInfo) => {
setLoading();
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};
try {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/auth", userInfo, config);
  console.log(res.data);
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
  loadAuthenticatedUser();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.response.data.errors);
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: err.response.data });
}
```

};

this is loadAuthenticatedUser function: I called this function in Homepage component ,and you can see above loginUser function i called it after successfully req ...

```
const loadAuthenticatedUser = async () => {
setLoading();
//set global header to check token exist if exist setToken
if (localStorage.token) {
  setToken(localStorage.token);
}
try {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");
  console.log(res);
  dispatch({ type: LOAD_AUTHENTICATED_USER, payload: res.data });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.response.data);
  dispatch({ type: LOAD_AUTH_ERROR, payload: err.response.data });
}
```

};

this is authReducer

```
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
  localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
  return {
    ...state,
    isAuthenticate: true,
    loading_State: false,
    user_State: action.payload.token,
  };

case LOAD_AUTHENTICATED_USER:
  return {
    ...state,
    isAuthenticate: true,
    loading_State: false,
    user_State: action.payload,
  };
case REGISTER_FAIL:
case LOGIN_FAIL:
case LOAD_AUTH_ERROR:
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
  return {
    ...state,
    error_State: action.payload.errors,
    isAuthenticate: false,
    loading_State: false,
    token_State: null,
    user_State: null,
  };

case LOGOUT:
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
  return {
    ...state,
    isAuthenticate: false,
    loading_State: false,
    token_State: null,
    user_State: null,
  };

case CLEAR_AUTH_ERRORS:
  return {
    ...state,
    error_State: null,
    user_State: null,
    loading_State: false,
  };
case SET_LOADING:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading_State: true,
  };

default:
  return {
    ...state,
  };
```

}

export default AuthReducer;

in HomePage component:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (isAuthenticate && !loading_State) {
  loadAuthenticatedUser();
}
clearAuthErrors();
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

}, [isAuthenticate, loading_State]);

this is my app.js file
render:

```
 return (
<AuthState>
  <ProfileState>
    <PostState>
      <AlertState>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

              <PrivateRoute
                Route
                exact
                path="/profile"
                component={UserProfile}
              />
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </AlertState>
    </PostState>
  </ProfileState>
</AuthState>
```

);

this is private route where it redirects once authenticated

```
return (
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={(props) =>
    !isAuthenticate && !loading_State ? (
      <Redirect to="/signin" />
    ) : (
      <Component {...props} />
    )
  }
/>
```

);

this is initial state after login[image] (used react dev tools) when i login in:

when i reload,  isAuthenticate value is set to false , but in authReducer you can see i set it to true in case of LOAD_AUTHENTICATED_USER  ... i called a function  in  homepage and in authState when ever successfully logined in ... but then it is not applying ... this is the state, if i reload when i am in home page

[image]

Comment: `when i reload the page is redirected to login page` There is no code anywhere in your question that would redirect a user.

Comment: i added the code ... you can find it above ..

Comment: As you mentioned in your question, 'when I reload the page is redirected to log in page'. You will need to try and authenticate the user by getting the token from storage when your application gets loaded. In homepage you are checking if the user is authenticated but this will never return true since all your states are getting reset after the refresh. You will need to run your `loadAuthenticatedUser()` in your app.js using `componentDidMount()`

Comment: If you are unsure on how to approach this I can give you an example answer.

Comment: if I were you, i would do the login, then check in developer tools, see if the token is indeed getting stored in local storage. I notice that you have written a lot of token related code without actually testing if the token storage is actually working. thats a mistake as well.

Comment: i added the images of state in developer tools .. pls go through ..

Comment: hi Dax, your explanation seem to be valid ... i am using hooks , have you worked with hooks..? if yes then ,  i think we can't run/call loadAuthenticatedUser() in app.js... i am intrested to know solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Upon browser refresh, unless explicitly persisted, your application state (component state and redux store) is completely reset: all variables content is erased.
In your case, you should make sure that PrivateRoute does not redirect when state has just been reset. For this, you should initialize `loading_State` as true.

Comment: what you said is correct but setting loading_State as true is not working ...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you need more help, I suggest you to produce a minimal and reproducible example, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example